# Python: printing with knowledge of current level of indentation

Tags: python, python-2.7, printing, iteration

Let's say I have next list:

```
xl = [[[0,0], [-1,1], [-2,2]], [[-3,3], [-4, 4], [-5,5]]
```

I want to print it and save hierarchy:

```
for el in xl:
    print el
    for iel in el:
        print ' '*4 + str(iel)
        for iiel in iel:
            print ' '*8 + str(iiel)

>>>
[[0, 0], [-1, 1], [-2, 2]]
    [0, 0]
        0
        0
    [-1, 1]
        -1
        1
    [-2, 2]
        -2
        2
[[-3, 3], [-4, 4], [-5, 5]]
    [-3, 3]
        -3
        3
    [-4, 4]
        -4
        4
    [-5, 5]
        -5
```

The hierarchy may be of any depth

I need some pythonic way to print with keeping current level of iterating (to don't manage of indent manually).

Going further my real case is more complicated (iterating over lxml entities). I just need a way to know current level when I am iterating over lists with for cycles.

Comment: Are you talking about `enumerate`? https://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#enumerate

Comment: In your complex case, are you talking about an lxml Element?

Comment: If you real case is about printing an lxml Element, then you may not need to manually code this, you should try something like - `print(etree.tostring(root, pretty_print=True))` .

Comment: @AnandSKumar about lists of such elements <class 'lxml.html.HtmlElement'>

Comment: A list of lxml elements  (no sublists, etc) right ?

Comment: @AnandSKumar thanks, but I know about this option. Actually this is not what I am trying to do.

Comment: @AnandSKumar check this https://repl.it/BLHv

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
def indent(thing, current_indentation=""):
    print current_indentation + str(thing)
    try:
        for item in thing:
            indent(item, " " * 4 + current_indentation)
    except TypeError:  # thing is not iterable
        pass

xl = [[[0,0], [-1,1], [-2,2]], [[-3,3], [-4, 4], [-5,5]]]
indent(xl)
```

Output:

```
[[[0, 0], [-1, 1], [-2, 2]], [[-3, 3], [-4, 4], [-5, 5]]]
    [[0, 0], [-1, 1], [-2, 2]]
        [0, 0]
            0
            0
        [-1, 1]
            -1
            1
        [-2, 2]
            -2
            2
    [[-3, 3], [-4, 4], [-5, 5]]
        [-3, 3]
            -3
            3
        [-4, 4]
            -4
            4
        [-5, 5]
            -5
            5
```

The point is that when you want to write code to handle arbitrarily nested loops you need recursion.

Comment: Thanks for your idea.

Answer (score 1):

I use 'isinstance' function to determine whether input date type is list

```
def print_by_hierarchy(data,indentation):
    if isinstance(data,list):
        space = 2*indentation
        for sub_data in data:
            print(' '*space + str(sub_data))
            print_by_hierarchy(sub_data,indentation +1)
    else:
        return 

test_data = [[[0,0], [-1,1], [-2,2]], [[-3,3], [-4, 4], [-5,5]]]
print_by_hierarchy(test_data,0)


output:
[[0, 0], [-1, 1], [-2, 2]]
  [0, 0]
    0
    0
  [-1, 1]
    -1
    1
  [-2, 2]
    -2
    2
[[-3, 3], [-4, 4], [-5, 5]]
  [-3, 3]
    -3
    3
  [-4, 4]
    -4
    4
  [-5, 5]
    -5
    5
```